# Selecting where only one unique max record exists in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have 2 tables, the first is the `t_cuti` table and the second table is `t_cuti_adjust`. Where the second table draws data from the first table.

1st table : t_cuti

[image]

And my 2nd table : t_cuti_adjust

[image]

This is display data for now:
[image]

And this is my expexted result:

[image]

I have problems when doing a query. I want to only display data from the largest ID with same the unique field `nik`.

My query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_daftar_adjust_saldo(
    character varying,
    character varying)
    RETURNS SETOF record 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
        rcd record;
        v_rumah_sakit alias for $1;
        v_unit alias for $2;

begin
for rcd in

select
    adj.id as id,
    cuti.nik as nik,
    nm_karyawan as nama_karyawan,
    nm_rs as rumah_sakit,
    nm_unit as unit,
    nm_jabatan as jabatan,
    cuti.saldo_cuti as saldo,
    adj.created_at as created_at
from
 --(select max(id) as id_tr, nik from t_cuti_adjust s group by s.nik ) x
 t_cuti cuti
 left join t_cuti_adjust adj on adj.nik=cuti.nik
 inner join m_karyawan kary on kary.nik=cuti.nik
 inner join m_rumah_sakit rs on rs.kd_rs=cuti.kd_rs
 inner join m_unit u on u.kd_unit=kary.kd_unit
 inner join m_jabatan j on j.kd_jabatan=kary.kd_jabatan

where 
case when v_rumah_sakit='' then 1=1 else nm_rs=v_rumah_sakit end
and case when v_unit='' then 1=1 else nm_unit=v_unit end

loop
return next rcd;
end loop;
/*
select * from fn_daftar_adjust_saldo('','') as (id bigint, nik character(9),nama_karyawan character varying,rumah_sakit character varying, unit character varying,jabatan character varying, saldo smallint, created_at timestamp with time zone)
*/
return;
end
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_daftar_adjust_saldo(character varying, character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Please _delete_ the images and instead include the sample data as _text_.  Then, also tell us how we can join the two tables together.

Comment: sorry I'm still new here, and haven't tried all the tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` for that. Restricted to the table `t_cuti` this means in your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(nik) id, nik, saldo_cuti FROM t_cuti
ORDER BY nik, id DESC;
```

Sorting by `id` ensures that the line with the largest value for `id` is always used. Postgres requires for `DISTINCT ON` queries with sorting to be sorted according to the attributes of the `DISTINCT ON` clause, too.

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(cuti.nik)
    adj.id as id,
    cuti.nik as nik,
    nm_karyawan as nama_karyawan,
    nm_rs as rumah_sakit,
    nm_unit as unit,
    nm_jabatan as jabatan,
    cuti.saldo_cuti as saldo,
    adj.created_at as created_at
FROM t_cuti cuti
 left join t_cuti_adjust adj on adj.nik=cuti.nik
 inner join m_karyawan kary on kary.nik=cuti.nik
 inner join m_rumah_sakit rs on rs.kd_rs=cuti.kd_rs
 inner join m_unit u on u.kd_unit=kary.kd_unit
 inner join m_jabatan j on j.kd_jabatan=kary.kd_jabatan

WHERE 
  case when v_rumah_sakit='' then 1=1 else nm_rs=v_rumah_sakit end
  and case when v_unit='' then 1=1 else nm_unit=v_unit end
ORDER BY cuti.nik, adj.id DESC
```

Comment: sir, i have more question. i need select year from created_at. I add this on select:
EXTRACT(year FROM adj.created_at) as year_created 
what return data type from year:
select * from fn_...('','') as (..., year_created ?)

Comment: its solved, i must add type data for new column :
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM adj.tanggal_ins)::int